# Pyspark Data Frame Filtering Syntax Error

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working with a Pyspark Data Frame using Pyspark version 1.6. Before exporting this data frame to a .CSV file I need to filter the data based on certain conditions using LIKE and OR operators on one particular column. To talk you through what I have done so far, I have created the initial data frame from multiple .JSON files. This data frame has been subsetted so only the required columns are included. A sqlContext temporary table has then been created. I have tried two different approaches so far, to use sqlContext and to use a Pyspark method.

sqlContext Method:

```
df_filtered = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from df WHERE text LIKE '#abc' OR 'abc' OR 'ghi' OR 'jkl' OR '#mno' OR '#1234' OR '56789'")
```

This is the error message I am presented with when running the sqlContext method:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '(text LIKE #abc || abc)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(text LIKE #abc || abc)' (boolean and string).;"
```

pyspark Method:

```
df_filtered.where((df["text"].like ("#abc")) || ((brexit_april_2016["text"].like ("abc")) || ((brexit_april_2016["text"].like ("#ghi")) || ((brexit_april_2016["text"].like ("jkl")) || ((brexit_april_2016["text"].like ("#mno")) || ((brexit_april_2016["text"].like ("1234")) || ((brexit_april_2016["text"].like ("56789"))
```

When running the pyspark method I am presented with a syntax error.

I'm sure it's something really simple that I've messed up on here but I would appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df_filtered = df.filter(
    (df.text.like("#abc")) | (df.text.like("abc")))
```

The "like" and or ("|") should be used like this in PySpark. You can add more conditions as per requirement.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Anshul, that's really helpful thank you. Annoyingly, I get an error when I try this although a different one than before. It says "Type Error: 'Column' object is not callable". Do I need to change the 'text' part of the code so it's in single quotation marks (')?

Comment: It was my fault, I hadn't put enough '|' symbols in my code (There's lots of conditions!). Thanks for your help!